# CET to GMT function in Java

Tags: java, date

Im trying to convert a CET time format to GMT.
The reason is because I am getting the date from XML and inserting it into antother system that uses GMT date format. So whatever date I am inserting is getting one day in the past.

Here I get from XML and insert it to Java object:

```
Date dob = DateUtils.fromXMLGregorianCalendar(customer.getDateOfBirth());
toYYYYMMDD(dob);
CETtoGMT(dob);
personalAccount.setBirthDate(dob);
```

My functions:

```
public static String toYYYYMMDD(Date day) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = formatter.format(day);
    return date;
}
public String CETtoGMT(Date cetDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String date = formatter.format(cetDate);
    return date;
}
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong but my tests say that I am using time zone of Oslo for the object personalAccount Birth date:

```
Sun Feb 24 00:00:00 CET 1990
cdate = {Gregorian$Date@3163} "1990-02-24T00:00:00.000+0100"
 cachedYear = 1990
 cachedFixedDateJan1 = 724642
 cachedFixedDateNextJan1 = 725007
 era = null
 year = 1990
 month = 2
 dayOfMonth = 24
 dayOfWeek = 1
 leapYear = false
 hours = 0
 minutes = 0
 seconds = 0
 millis = 0
 fraction = 0
 normalized = true
 zoneinfo = {ZoneInfo@3165} "sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Oslo",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=141,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Oslo,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]"
 zoneOffset = 3600000
 daylightSaving = 0
 forceStandardTime = false
 locale = null
```

Comment: in 'toYYYYMMDD' function you forgot to set time zone. btw, it would become a trivial problem for you, if you create a unit test and debug it in IDE.

Comment: You should document important pieces of your Question, such as what is `DateUtils`. I might guess Apache Commons Lang, but you should not make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
customer.getDateOfBirth()                     // Assuming this call returns a `XMLGregorianCalendar`. 
    .toGregorianCalendar​()                    // Convert `XMLGregorianCalendar` to the legacy class `GregorianCalendar`, en route to a `ZonedDateTime` in next line.
    .toZonedDateTime()                        // Convert from `GregorianCalendar` to `ZonedDateTime`, from legacy class to modern class.
    .toOffsetDateTime()                       // Convert to `OffsetDateTime` to better document that we are moving to an offset-from-UTC rather than a full time zone.
    .withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Adjust into UTC. Same moment in time, same point on the timeline, but viewed through a different wall-clock time.
    .toLocalDate()                            // Extract a date-only value, without time zone and without time-of-day.
    .toString()                               // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD.
;
```

## `Date` is UTC, but its `toString` is not

The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment in UTC. Unfortunately, its `toString` method confusingly applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating a string. This has been explained many many many times already on Stack Overflow.

## Avoid legacy classes

`Date` is one of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes.

## java.time

You can convert from the legacy classes by calling new methods added to the old classes. If your code is returning a [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) object, convert first to a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

```
GregorianCalendar gc = customer.getDateOfBirth().toGregorianCalendar​() ;  // Returning a XMLGregorianCalendar, then converting to a GregorianCalendar.
```

Convert into java.time. The counterpart to `GregorianCalendar​` is [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Your goal is UTC. So convert to `OffsetDateTime`, then adjust into UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Apparently you want the date-only of that UTC adjustment, so extract a `LocalDate` to represent a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

To be clear to all readers… Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal). We had to go through all these steps to preserve the vital time zone (or offset-from-UTC) information so as to get the correct date.

## Strings

Your desired output seems to be a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

## Time zones

By the way, never use `CET` or other such 3-4 letter pseudo-zones. These are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );  // Or "Europe/Berlin" or "Africa/Tunis" etc.
ZonedDateTime zdt = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I work with integration so I have to support different formats for diffrent systems. My initial goal was to convert it not to a String but to a java.util.Calendar.

Comment: @Solo If at all possible, I suggest using only the standard ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values as text. For zoned values, the `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends the standard by appending the name of the zone in square brackets. Usually best to exchange UTC values, represented in java.time as an `Instant`.